# Texture nodes not being applied on stair

Tags: shaders, pbr

I'm trying to make a model of a village house but I'm stuck in wanting to put an PBR material into some stairs.

I get this weird orientation of the PBR on some faces of the stairs. Is their any way I can adjust the orientation and scale of a PBR only on the selected faces?

[image: Object]

[image: This is the node scheme that I'm using]

Comment: Try selecting your stair model, going to UV editing mode, hitting "u" to unwrap, and selecting "Project from view"

Comment: Yes as Bentley says you need to unwrap your stairs, not sure about the Project from View though, try Smart UV Project for example

Comment: Thank you for suggesting UV Map, it worked. It didn't occur to me to use UV Map, maybe I was thinking that with Nodes they will work the same way. [![final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlNay.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlNay.jpg)